# Getting UIButton postition

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

I have a tableview, and a collectionview in a cell of this tableview. And a button in a cell of this collectionview. I need the position of this button( where it is in the screen ) when it is pressed. I couldn't get the correct values.

Comment: Use converters,  each `UIView` is a `UICoordinateSpace` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace.   So, simplest way is to use `button.convert(button.bounds, to: UIScreen.currentCoordinateSpace)`, this will convert the bounds rect from the UIButton coordinate space into UIScreen current coordinate space

Comment: For Swift 4: button.convert(button.bounds, to: UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace) solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use converters, each UIView is a UICoordinateSpace, also UIScreen has 2 UICoordinateSpace objects (`currentCoordinateSpace` and `fixedCoordinateSpace`).

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicoordinatespace .

So, simplest way is to use `button.convert(button.bounds, to: UIScreen.main.coordinateSpace)`, this will convert the bounds rect from the `UIButton` coordinate space into `UIScreen` current coordinate space.